# Cast xml to string in LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq

Is there a way to cast an xml to a string in a Linq query. Something like this, but in LINQ:

```
select TOP(10) * from PackageSessionNodes
where CAST(Interactions as nvarchar(max)) like '%asset id%'
order by PackageSessionNodeId desc
```

This doesn't work:

```
var packageSessionNodes = from psn in db.PackageSessionNodes
                          where psn.Interactions.Contains("asset")
                          select psn;
```

Interactions is a XML Column in SQL2008 Server.

Comment: Can you let us know what kind of Data Type SubSonic uses for Interactions?

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you mean like:

```
var packageSessionNodes = from psn in db.PackageSessionNodes
                          where psn.Interactions.Contains("asset")
                          select psn.ToString();
```

XML in Linq is represented by the XNode family of types.  XNode.ToString() returns the [xml representation of the node and its children.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx)

Or, do you mean

```
var packageSessionNodes = from psn in db.PackageSessionNodes
                          where ((string)psn.Interactions).Contains("asset")
                          select psn;
```

assuming that psn is a type that has a public property Interactions which is an XElement.  Of course, if it is, you should be parsing the XML instead of seeing if the xml text contains a specific string.

Comment: I meant the second one. Well, parsing the xml in the linq query with linq to xml doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var packageSessionNodes = from psn in db.PackageSessionNodes
                          where psn.Interactions.ToString().Contains("asset")
                          select psn
```

Depending on what Data Type SqlMetal decided to use for your XML Column (typically either XNode or XElement I believe), `ToString()` will return the XML as a String which should work for you.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's Linq to SubSonic, so maybe the problem is that SubSonic doesn't support it.